# How can I create this switch behaviour via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

First of all, I am really sorry that I could not give specific title about the issue. I have a .net 4.6.1 view page.

[image]

I want to create this feature.

Depending on the DepositType, the DefaultDeposit should display either a £ sign or %.

One of the logic, I already tried was to create another property called DefaultDepositPercent. Create a Input Box which is hidden underneath and use Jquery to display or hide this Input Box. Then in my service layer, pass the value inputted in the DefaultDepositPercent to DefaultDeposit.
However, there was an inconvenience that the mvc form also passes the DefaultDeposit value as 0. And there is also an issue of someone fiddling with the Javascript.

I have googled but could not find any answers. It is likely because I could describe the issue in few words.

Any direction would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: @reddy Yes. The pound and percent sign are generated by <span class="input-group-addon">&permil;</span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bootstrap we just have to place the `span` tag above or below the `input` element to get the Prefix or Postfix effect. [More Details Here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups)

So the idea is first not to have this post / prefix `span` tag initially but add it either on DOM ready event or when the drop down selection changes using Jquery [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) and [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/). Here is a working sample. Hope this is helpful.

```js
$(function() {

  SetUpDepositTextBox();  // set up the input box once when DOM is ready

  $('.DepositType').on('change', function() {
    SetUpDepositTextBox(); // set up the text box when ever the dropdown changes
  });
});

function SetUpDepositTextBox() {
  $('#depositDefaultWrapper span').remove();
  var $this = $('.DepositType');

  if ($this.val() == "Amount") {
    $('<span class="input-group-addon">£</span>').insertBefore('#depositDefaultWrapper input');
  } else {
    $('<span class="input-group-addon">%</span>').insertAfter('#depositDefaultWrapper input');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 Deposit Type
<select class="DepositType form-control">
  <option value="Amount">Amount</option>
  <option value="Percentage">Percentage</option>
</select>

Default Deposit
<div id="depositDefaultWrapper" class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="10">
</div>
```

Comment: @yuvs glad I could help you